# angular: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'webpack'?

Tags: angular, npm

i was working on a project , after i upgraded the angular version i started getting this error can anyone please help me determine this error ? 
 i have tried deleting node_modules,package-lock.json and reinstalling angular and cli but not able to fix this.
npm start gives me this error 
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'webpack'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder\gitlab repos\lms-dashboard\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
  See "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-9d5ZFx\angular-errors.log" for further details.
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! syscall spawn
  npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  npm ERR! errno ENOENT
  npm ERR! scssdestmoney@1.0.0 start: `ng serve --port 4201`
  npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the scssdestmoney@1.0.0 start script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-27T06_17_52_442Z-debug.log 
**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "scssdestmoney",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build-prod": "bash ./scripts/ng.sh build --prod --aot --env=prod",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4201",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.7",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33",
    "@zoomus/websdk": "^1.8.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.2.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.2",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "binding": "^3.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^4.3.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "websdk": "^3.0.0",
    "wowjs": "1.1.3",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^6.14.5",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your package.json ?

Comment: updated the package.json above

Answer (score 1):

Try to just install it with `npm install webpack`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **npm install**
and check whether the project is getting build if its still not working

Try **npm update**